# when i use ajax post json to web server(Nodejs), but the web server can't receive the data from client

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, node.js

the client code :

```
self.getjson = function () {
    var timeinfo = new Object();
    timeinfo.time = self.time;
    timeinfo.address = self.address;
    timeinfo.info = self.info;

    return JSON.stringify(timeinfo);
};

alert(self.getjson());

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        //beforeSend:function(){$(".info").fadeIn('slow').html("正在提交，请稍后");},
        url:'/user/add/timetemp',
        data: self.getjson(),
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {

            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        },
        success: function(data){

        }

})
```

the server code app.js:

```
router.route('/user/add/timetemp')
.post(function(req,res){

 console.log(req.body);      // your JSON
 res.send(req.body);    // echo the result back
```

});

the answer from client:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg9Rp.png)
there has data in the client.

the answer from server:

but the server is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body):

> **`req.body`**
>
> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. **By default, it is `undefined`, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser) and [multer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multer).**

*(My emphasis.)* It continues with:

> The following example shows how to use body-parsing middleware to populate req.body.
>
> ```
> var app = require('express')();
> var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
> var multer = require('multer'); // v1.0.5
> var upload = multer(); // for parsing multipart/form-data
>
> app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
> app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> app.post('/profile', upload.array(), function (req, res, next) {
>   console.log(req.body);
>   res.json(req.body);
> });
> ```

---

Side notes:

1. All of these variables on `self` are global variables. Global variables are a Bad Thing™. :-) Generally best to put your code in a scoping function and use locals within that scoping function.

2. `new Object` is almost never needed. Your `getjson` function can be much simpler:

```
self.getjson = function () {
    return JSON.stringify({
        time: self.time,
        address: self.address,
        info: self.info
    });
};
```

or *(slightly more convenient when debugging)*:

```
self.getjson = function () {
    var timeinfo = {
        time: self.time,
        address: self.address,
        info: self.info
    };
    return JSON.stringify(timeinfo);
};
```

3. There's no need for your `beforeSend` callback on `ajax`; just use the built-in `contentType` option:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //beforeSend:function(){$(".info").fadeIn('slow').html("正在提交，请稍后");},
    url: '/user/add/timetemp',
    data: self.getjson(),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {

    }
});
```

Comment: According to your suggestion , the question was finally solved . The reason for this problem is that use beforeSend callback on ajax. just use the built-in contentType. thank your very much.

Comment: @kevin: Really? Interesting! Well, glad that sorted it out.

Comment: But i don't know why no need for  beforeSend callback on ajax. so i will hard work to study. thank you